Puppet agent -t throwing "Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'classes'"
I have a product to deploy, that has already consolidated hieradata.
I have only added only file in hieradata (/opt/<product>/hieradata/data/roles/all_in_one.yaml) to add some custom details.
That file starts with
---

classes:
  - java
  - mysql::client
  - mysql::server
  - resource_tree

But, whenever I issue /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent -t to start the changes, the following error is thrown:

2024-07-30T17:24:56.094Z ERROR [qtp1481164360-36] [puppetserver] Puppet Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'classes'
2024-07-30T17:24:56.095Z ERROR [qtp1481164360-36] [puppetserver] Puppet Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'classes' on node ip-172-xxxxxx.compute.internal
2024-07-30T17:24:56.095Z ERROR [qtp1481164360-36] [puppetserver] Puppet Server Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'classes' on node ip-172-xxxxxx.compute.internal


Before adding this hieradata to /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests,  /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules, /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera.yaml and /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/data the sync used to work, so I imagine that's something wrong in the hieradata.

[root@ip-172-xxxxxx ~]# sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent -t
Info: Using environment 'production' Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Caching catalog for ip-172-xxxxxx.compute.internal
Info: Applying configuration version '1721921132'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds


I expected that this agent sync would complete and apply the changes from the hieradata.

The YAML Hiera data you present looks fine.  I can only conclude that Hiera is not consulting it when the relevant lookup() call is performed.  That would presumably be a function of the relevant hierarchy definition files (up to three of them), but you haven't given us any details of those.  The location of the affected lookup() call in the Puppet manifests matters a bit too.

Alternatively, puppetserver ordinarily runs as a non-privileged user.  If your update caused the ownership or permissions of the updated file to change, then it may be that Puppet is not consulting it because it no longer has permission to read it.

I've foud the solution.
The product that I'm deploying, relies on a tag to determine which roles are going to be applied and deployed.
So after creating the following, it worked.
$ cat /opt/puppetlabs/facter/facts.d/dmps_node.yaml
node_type: all_in_one
